# Javafx relocate and rotate

Tags: animation, javafx, rotation, relocation

i have an node in javafx which are moving in a timeline. 
Now i want rotate the node also.
I tried it but everytime the node doesn't hold the path anymore and "fly away".  Is there a way to relcate and rotate (I tried it with rotatetransition)?

Edit:

That is my View -Class

```
public class MyView extends ImageView{


public MyView (Image image) {
    super(image);

    RotateTransition transition = new RotateTransition();
    transition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    transition.setNode(this);
    transition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10));
    transition.setFromAngle(5);
    transition.setToAngle(5;
    transition.setAutoReverse(true);
    transition.play(); // */

}
}
```

On another class i have this:

```
 private void startMoveAnimation(MyView[] views) {
    x++;
    y++;
    this.timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    moveEvent = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 for(View view: views){
                      view.relocate(x,y);
                 }

            }
        }
    };

    KeyFrame moveKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(SPEED), moveEvent);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(moveKeyFrame);

    timeline.play(); // */
}
```

x and y are double values.

Comment: show some code, so we can try to help you

Comment: I add an example

Answer (score 3):

Using transforms gives you better control of the order of the transformations. Furthermore some transfroms allow you to specify a pivot point, which is not possible for e.g. the `Node.rotate` property. Transforms in a list are applied "right to left". (The transform with the highest index is applied first).

The following example shows how to move a rectangle rotating arount its own center (even though the cycle resets to the original position instead of continuously moving in the same direction, but the properties of the transforms can be animated independently in arbitrary ways):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle view = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    // pivot point = center of rect
    Rotate rotate = new Rotate(0, 50, 50);
    Translate translate = new Translate();

    // rotate first, then move
    view.getTransforms().addAll(translate, rotate);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(translate.xProperty(), 0d),
                    new KeyValue(translate.yProperty(), 0d), new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(translate.xProperty(), 300d),
                    new KeyValue(translate.yProperty(), 500d), new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 360d)));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    Pane root = new Pane(view);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the transforms are applied right-to-left and not left-to-right? If you have a `Rotate` at index `0` and a `Translate` at index `1`, it appears to me that the node first rotates and then translates along the _rotated_ axes. If it were right-to-left wouldn't it first translate along the _non-rotated_ axes and then rotate? Or am I simply missing something conceptually?

Comment: @Slaw If you swap the transforms, the node is first moved to a different position by the translate; this does not affect the pivot point of the rotation. The rotate then rotates the whole thing around the pivot point. Imagine you want to draw a circle using a compass. The center is (0,0). We'll start of with the needle in the paper and the pencil (roughly) at (0,0). then we set the radius ("translate the pencil") and later we rotate the pencil around (0,0). This is different from the output of the program above (considering the center of the rect to be (0,0)).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was under the mistaken impression that both (1) the pivot point was bound to the center of the `Rectangle` and (2) the `Translate` was modifying the `x` and `y` properties which would affect the local bounds which in turn would make the center point, and thus pivot point, move with the `Rectangle`. Both those impressions are wrong (which I should have known but for some reason forgot). Do you know where, if at all, this order is documented? Because [this](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms()) doesn't seem to specify.

Comment: @Slaw In the javadoc it doesn't seem to indicate this very clearly. However several transforms indicate that a column vector is multiplied from the right side and that combining matrices works the same as adding both to the `transforms` list. (Just don't take a look at `Rotate`; the info there is wrong). [`Affine.transform`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Affine.html#append(javafx.scene.transform.Transform)) states that the order of the matrix multiplication is the same as in the transforms list and the class description shows the matrix

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would try first:
Put the node into a Group. Add the Group to the parent instead of the node. Do the translate animation on the Group and do the rotate animation on the node itself. This is just a first guess which I cannot try out because you haven't provided a minimal reproducible example.